# Ordered Array. Resize does not allow ordered elements

Tags: c++, arraylist, resize, push

i am making an ordered array.  Where the elements are in order. Example 1,2,3,4,5,6,77,89,100,201. I ask the user to enter in the size of the array.  This is fine and the push function will put the elements in ordered.  But when the arrayList is resized,The elements are no longer being allocated in an ordered fashion.

Here is my code:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Array::Resize
//  Description:    Resize the array to a new size.
//  Arguments:      p_size.  The new size of the Array.
//-------------------------------------------------------
    void Resize(int p_size)//resizes the array to the size of p_size
    {
        cout << "Did i get this far ";
        if(p_size < 0)//checks if new size is less than 0
        {
            cout << "ERROR! Size of an array can not be less than 0!" << endl;
        }
        else//else its ok to continue
        {
            Datatype* newArray = new Datatype[p_size];//creates a pointer newArray that points at a new array
            if(newArray == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            cout << "Did i get this far ";
            int min;

            if(p_size < size)//checks the if the new array is smaller than the old one
                min = p_size;
            else//else its going to be bigger
                min = size;
            cout << "Did i get this far ";
            int index;
            int temp = num_elements;//puts num_elements into a temporary variable called temp
            num_elements = 0;//num_elements is set to 0
            for(index = 0; index < min; index++)
            {
                newArray[index] = m_array[index];//places everything from the old array into the new array that will fit.
                if(num_elements < temp)//if the num_elements is less than temp(the original num_elements)
                {
                    num_elements++;//increment num_elements. This will keep incrementing to create the new num_elements based the number of elements cut off in the resize
                }
            }
            size = p_size;//sets the old size to be equal to the new size
            cout << "Did i get this far ";
            if(m_array != 0)
            cout << "\nI am just about to delete ";
            //delete[] m_array;//deletes the old array
            m_array = newArray;//makes m_array point at the new array
            newArray = 0;//makes newArray a null pointer
        }
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name:             Push
// Description:      
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void push(Datatype p_item)
{
    if(num_elements == size)//checks if the array is full and needs to be resized
    {
        Resize(size + g_size);//calls the resize function
    }

    int pos = num_elements;
    for(int x=0;x<num_elements;x++)
    {
        if(p_item < m_array[x])
        {
        pos=x;
        }
    }

    //loops through the array from high to low moving all values to the right
    //to make space for the passed in value until it gets to the right place
    for(int index = num_elements; index >= pos; index--)
    {
        m_array[index] = m_array[index-1];//moves the values to the right
    }
        m_array[pos] = p_item;//the passed in value is positioned into its ordered position
        num_elements++;

    cout<< "Num Elements " << num_elements;
    cout<< "Size " <<size;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           template <class Datatype>   
//  Description:        

    //--------------------------------
```

---

```
template <class Datatype>
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Class: OrderedArray.            
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class OrderedArray
{
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Member Variables.           
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private:
Datatype* m_array;
int size;
int g_size;
int num_elements;   //Counter for the number of elements in the Array.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Constructor.
//  Description:    Constructs the Array.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OrderedArray(int p_size)
{
    //Sets the Array size.
    m_array = new Datatype[p_size]; 
    size = p_size;
    grow_size = 1;  
    //How many elements are in the Array.
    num_elements = 0;               
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: unrelated, but you need to `delete` the old array, or use `std::vector` as your data store. EDIT: ah why is it commented out?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: @KarthikT Yeah i have another problem when deleting the array. It causes a run-time error.  But il deal with that once i fix this :).  Thanks though.

Comment: Do you mean that resize is ruining the order? or that resize followed by push is not working as intended?

Comment: About your Run  time error, you need `{}` around the `if` which checks that your array exists.

Comment: @KarthikT.  The push will order the elements until the resize happens. It then no longer works.

Comment: Could you please show us your constructor ?

Comment: @Pendo826 Hey i just edited in the constructor :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using copies of last element of your m as new elements instead of default-constructed instances. So the last elements will be grater or equal to all preceding elements of the array.